# Missing notation in one of the test questions

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials, binomial-coefficients

I am looking at STEP (Cambridge produced test for maths) questions and have stumbled upon this question. Does anyone know what notation is missing here in the section **i)**. Please do not provide me with a solution, I want to have a go at this question.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re to consider

$$\sum_{r=0}^n\left[(r+1)^k-r^k\right]$$

and show that

$$kS_{k-1}(n)=(n+1)^k-(n+1)-\binom{k}2S_{k-2}(n)-\binom{k}3S_{k-3}(n)-\ldots-\binom{k}{k-1}S_1(n)\;.$$

Comment: @isquared-KeepitReal: You’re welcome!

Comment: this was an amazing question! Beautiful and neat result!